# How to perform graph traversals with multiple collections in ArangoDB

Tags: nosql, graph-databases, arangodb, aql, arangodb-graph

I have a graph consisting of 3 document collections and 2 edge collections. I want to perform filtering from one doc collection but need to show the result from all three doc collections.

Graph: AssetWorkTime

Documents Collection: assetnew (consists name of asset), timenew (consists the start date of renovation), and Work (consists type of renovation)

Edge Collection: AssetRenoTimeNew (Connecting assetnew and timenew) and WorkTimeNew (Connecting timenew and Work)

[This a part of my graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1Q12.png)

```
FOR c IN timenew
FILTER c.startdate>="2020-01-01"
      FOR v, e, p IN 1..1 outbound c GRAPH 'AssetWorkTime'
     RETURN {AssetName:v.AssetName,  Date:c.startdate, RenoJob:v.WorkName}
```

This is the query that I have done. I want to know which assets have gone through renovation after 1/1/2020 and what type of renovation that has been done.

[This is the result that I got. The result are correct except for it does not show the name of the assets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywSos.png)

I've gone through the documentation and other questions in stackoverflow but couldn't find a way to get this. Thanks!

Comment: Please read up on how to ask good questions - for one: Don't link to images, avoid using images of textual data - post the actual data/text.  I suggest you debug your query by looking at v, e, and p in their entirety and try to play with the paths length , to get a feel for what is happening with this kind of query.

Comment: Thank you. Will improve next time. I have played around with the path length but still couldnt get the desired answer @TomRegner